# How to match the colors of different RGB mosaic rasters?

Tags: qgis, rgb, histogram

I am beginner in QGIS. I want to classify many  RGB rasters (see picture) but their colors don´t match. As you can see, the green polygon shows the same land cover class (meadow) but in each tile the color for this class is totally different.

I would like to "re-paint" them or match their histograms somehow. They overlap sligthly (like a mosaic), maybe not enough for matching overlapping features. I would like to take a sample from one image, tell the program that the sample is a meadow, and re-paint all the other meadows in the other images. Is it possible to do this?

[image]

I tried to do it in arcGIS, but always got an error. Answers in QGIS or R are welcomed.

I am running QGIS 2.12.3 in a PC.

Comment: the colors could be different but the values could be the same. I don't think that this is the case, but you should first check the values on two or three images.

Comment: @radouxju I plot the histograms of each and are totally different.